Hiding button if last page is reached
I have tried searching the web for solutions on how to do this, not to mention youtube from other developers but cannot seem to find answer i am looking for.
I am trying to create a ButtonView where I have 2 buttons at the bottom of the page: "Next" and "Previous".  The issue I am having is if the user reaches the last page in the loop, I want to be able to hide the "Next" button so that only the "Previous" button shows only when on last page and both buttons show when on any other page other than the last page.
Below is the code I have for my ButtonsView:
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonsView: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let buttons = ["Previous", "Next"]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { buttonLabel in
                Button(action: { buttonAction(buttonLabel) }, label: {
                    Text(buttonLabel)
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 44)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.27))
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                })
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .padding()
    }

    func buttonAction(_ buttonLabel: String) {
        withAnimation {
            if buttonLabel == "Previous" && selection > 0 {
                selection -= 1
            } else if buttonLabel == "Next" && selection < pages.count - 1 {
                selection += 1
            } 
        }
    } 
}

In the buttonAction func, I believe is where we need to implement the code to hide the "Next" button if we reach the last page but I am unaware of how to do so.
What code would I implement to hide the "Next" button when I reach the last page and unhide the "Next" button when we are NOT on last page?

To answer my own question, I came up with the following:

I added a new variable totalPages of type Int which is equal to 'pages.count' -> total pages

I added an if clause above the Button code shouldShowButton using buttonLabel and the function for showShowButton.

Basically, if we reach the last pages, which is pages.count (total number of pages) then selection < totalPages - 1, otherwise we show the button.


Below is the updated code:
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonsView: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let buttons = ["Previous", "Next"]
    let totalPages: Int // NEWLY ADDED

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { buttonLabel in
                // NEWLY ADDED:
                if shouldShowButton(buttonLabel: buttonLabel) { 

                    Button(action: { buttonAction(buttonLabel) }, label: {
                        Text(buttonLabel)
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 44)
                            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.27))
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    })
                } // NEWLY ADDED
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .padding()
    }
    
    // NEWLY ADDED
    func shouldShowButton(buttonLabel: String) -> Bool {
        if buttonLabel == "Next" {
            return selection < totalPages - 1
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func buttonAction(_ buttonLabel: String) {
        withAnimation {
            if buttonLabel == "Previous" && selection > 0 {
                selection -= 1
            } else if buttonLabel == "Next" && selection < pages.count - 1 {
                selection += 1
            }
        }
    } 
}

You will see // NEWLY ADDED where the new code that I added into my original code.
